# Find possible integer values for $x$ using angle-edge relationship in triangle.

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles

> In triangle $\triangle{ABC}$, $BH$ is the height of $AC$. $|AB|=|AC|=10$. $|BC|=x$. And inequality $2\cdot\measuredangle{BAC}>\measuredangle{ABC}+\measuredangle{ACB}$ is given. How many possible integer values $x$ can be?

Here is a figure for question:

[image]
**My attempt:** I know that $\measuredangle{ABC}=\measuredangle{ACB}$ due to the fact that $|AB|=|AC|$. Let $\alpha=\measuredangle{ABC}=\measuredangle{ACB}$. So i have $\measuredangle{BAC}=180-2\alpha$. According to given inequality i have:

$$
360-4\alpha>\alpha+\alpha \\
6\alpha<360 \\
\alpha<60
$$
So
$$
\measuredangle{BAC}=180-2\alpha>60
$$
I can conclude $x>10$ according to last fact since we have isosceles triangle. I get a lower limit. If i write an inequality in triangle $\triangle{ABC}$:
$$
10-10<x<10+10 \\
x<20
$$
And this the upper bound i've found. I can combine them and write:
$$
10<x<20
$$
But seems like i can't compress the inequality enough because the book says that the answer is $4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $H$ between $A$ and $C$ then $\measuredangle A<90^{\circ}$, which gives $10<x<10\sqrt2$ and four values of $x$.

Comment: There is no such a requirement and $\angle A$ can be obtuse because x can be 16.

Comment: @Mick If $H$ between $A$ and $C$ it does not happen.

Comment: I mean there is no such restriction -- requiring H to lie between A and C.